# How to extend a class with a different constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I am having difficulty extending a person class to  a patient class

I have a Person class with a constructor looking like

```
  public Person(String firstname,String surname) {
        fFirstname=firstname;
        fSurname=surname;
    }
```

I then have a Patient Class

public class Patient extends Person

I want to have a constructor for a patient looking roughly like

```
public Patient(String hospNumber) {
    fFirstname = lookup(hospNumber,"firstname");
    fSurname = lookup(hospNumber,"surname");
}
```

However I get a complaint that the Patient constructor needs (String,String).
I can see why this is, but can't see how to extend the person class for a patient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the result of those two method calls to the `super` constructor:

```
public Patient(String hospNumber) {
    super(lookup(hospNumber,"firstname"), lookup(hospNumber,"surname"));
}
```

Those methods have to be static, since the `this` they would otherwise been called on hasn't been constructed yet when they're invoked.

Comment: I had tried that but had the two lines creating fFirstname and fSurname before the super(fFirstname,fSurname) this generated an error saying super had to be first line. Your suggestion works fine. Thanks

Comment: @TonyWolff  super has to be the first line always.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can have a default constructor in `Person` class

```
public Person() {

}
```

Or

You need to call constructor the Person class using `super` method as its a 2-arg constructor

```
public Patient(String hospNumber) {
    super(lookup(hospNumber,"firstname"), lookup(hospNumber,"firstname"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the patient constructor to this.

```
public Patient(String hospNumber) {
   super(lookup(hospNumber,"firstname"), lookup(hospNumber,"surname"));
}
```

But the `lookup` method needs to be static in order to do this.
Otherwise you will have to change it to:

```
public Patient(String hospNumber, String firstname, String surname) {
  super(firstname,surname);
}
```

Or something similar.

Finally you could also add another constructor to the Person class. like `Person()` and set the rest of the details later. this way you don't have to even write super() on the constructor of the patient.

Side notes:
A class can have more than 1 constructors as long as they do not have the same parameters.

`super()` calls the constructor of the super-class (that class from which this class inherits).